# How to move next button in checkout to sidebar and keep it's behaviour. Magento 2.3

Tags: checkout, shipping-methods, shipping-address, magento2.3.0, knockout

As in question title. **Button** is placed in `Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`

I need to **move** it under **sidebar section** or create **new button** which will act the same like old one. I know how to create a new button and move it under or inside sidebar, but i don;t know how to force `shipping address` and `shipping method validation` after click on it.

The google search did not bring clear or working results.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Robert_Szczepaniec@: did you get the solution.?  i need to configure the same thing .. please update if you have.